# Unable to install asterisk-core library on linux centos

Tags: linux, installation, centos, asterisk

I try to install on a linux Centos x86_64 a library named asterisk-core-11.20.0-1_centos6.x86_64 which not found the library libsrtp.so.0 present at the path /usr/lib/64. the error is:

```
Error: Package: asterisk-core-11.20.0-1_centos6.x86_64 (ict)
       Requires: libsrtp.so.0()(64bit)
```

could you please give me some advice ?

regards

Comment: I think asterisk-core library asks for a libsrtp library with a SONAME as libsrtp.so.0 and the current SONAME installed by YUM is libsrtp.so.1

Answer (score 1):

This library provided in epel repository. You could add it by command `yum install epel-release`, and then install it by command `yum install libsrtp`.

Comment: I already installed as you wrote. the library libsrtp.so.0 is present at the path /usr/lib/64 but it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: @FabioMarano could you add more details how you try to install it, and show full output.

Comment: I think asterisk-core library ask for a libsrtp library with a SONAME as libsrtp.so.0 and the current SONAME installed by YUM is libsrtp.so.1

Answer (score 0):

solved :-)) with asterisk repo i installed the right libsrtp.so.0 with SONAME libsrtp.so.0 :-)))))))